# PHP sort integers based on a selected integer

Tags: php, sorting

I'm having trouble with the PHP for sorting integers starting from 1 to some value where the sorting is based on a selected integer whose value is between 1 and some value.

Here's how i'd like the function to look:

```
function sort_integers($count, $selected_value){
     ....sort()...?
}
```

So if the `$count=7` and you `$selected_value=3`, then the `sort_integers()` function would return this:

```
3,4,5,6,7,1,2
```

And if the `$count=4` and you `$selected_value=2`, then the `sort_integers()` function would return this:

```
2, 3, 4, 1
```

I think I need a 3rd variable that increments such that I can do a comparison but my head is starting to hurt thinking about how that would be done. Thoughts?

Comment: Workaround: sort the array as usual, then do some splicing to move the first part to the end of the array, splitting at your $selected_value

Comment: you want to sort integers or just display all integers from $selected_value to $count in ascending order followed by 1 to $count-1 in ascending order?

Comment: @MarcB can you share some code to explain your workaround?

Comment: http://php.net/array_splice to lop off the 'front' of the array, then you simply stuff that piece onto the end and you've got your 'sort starts at number x' array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I got you right, I would do this:

```
function sort_integers($count, $selected_value){
    $res = array();
    for($i = $selected_value; $i <= $count; ++$i)
      $res[] = $i;
    for($i = 1; $i < $selected_value; ++$i)
      $res[] = $i;
    return $res;
}
```

or using builtin functions:

```
function sort_integers($count, $selected_value){
    return array_merge(range($selected_value, $count), 
                       range(1, $selected_value - 1));
}
```

This assumes you just want to align the values like in your example and there is no given array you want to have sorted (as you did not pass one in and did not mention one).

Answer (score 2):

The range is already sorted, you only split it and reverse the parts:

```
$count = 7;
$selected = 3;

$range = range(1, $count);

if (--$selected)
{
    $sort = array_splice($range, 0, $selected);
    $sort = array_merge($range, $sort);
} else {
    $sort = $range;
}
```

Or more straight forward:

```
function sort_integers($count = 7, $selected = 3) {
    if (! $count = max(0, $count)) return array();
    if (--$selected && $selected < $count) {
        return array_merge(range($selected+1,$count), range(1, $selected));
    }
    return range(1, $count);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

without arrays, this should work..

```
function sort_integers($count, $selected_value)
{
    for($x = $selected_value; $x<=$count;$x++)
    {
        echo $x.",";
    }

    for($x=1; $x < $selected_value;$x++)
    {
        echo $x.",";
    }
}
```

Oh, and it might leave an extra comma in the end..